# How to join a table and aggregate the data by a different field than the key

Tags: sql-server, join

I try to join a few tables in Dynamics AX and get all information per A.PARTYID on 1 row. However I have to join the other tables in a more detailed relationship.

Currently I try to join the following tables this way:

```
SELECT 
A.PARTYID
,C.EMAIL
,C.PHONE
,C.RECID
FROM DIRPARTYTABLE A

LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYECOMMUNICATIONRELA2608 B
ON B.PARTYID = A.PARTYID

LEFT JOIN DIRECOMMUNICATIONADDRESS C
ON C.RECID = B.RECID

WHERE
B.PARTYID = 00000225
```

And this is the result:

```
PARTYID     MAIL                PHONE         RECID
000000225   asdf@gmail.com      NULL          5637146657
000000225   NULL                0612345678    5637176698
```

However I want to aggregate the information by PARTYID and leave out the RECID, since I'm not interested in that, like this:

```
PARTYID     MAIL                PHONE         
000000225   asdf@gmail.com      0612345678
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can adjust the code to make it work?

Sorry the question may seem vague, since I don't entirely know what keywords to use to describe this.

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: Can you supply sample data? I think the problem is your data, not your query? Why do you have separate rows to store phone number and email address? They should be a single row.

Comment: Hi. "aggregate the information by PARTYID and leave out the RECID" is not clear. Also it's not clear from your example desired output. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear specification. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just

```
SELECT 
      A.PARTYID
     ,MAX(C.EMAIL) Email
     ,MAX(C.PHONE) Phone
FROM DIRPARTYTABLE A
LEFT JOIN DIRPARTYECOMMUNICATIONRELA2608 B
ON B.PARTYID = A.PARTYID
LEFT JOIN DIRECOMMUNICATIONADDRESS C
ON C.RECID = B.RECID
WHERE
B.PARTYID = '00000225' --00000225 is a string not a number
GROUP BY A.PARTYID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT  SQ1.PARTYID,
        MAX(SQ1.MAIL) AS Mail,
        MAX(SQ1.PHONE) AS Phone
FROM    (
            VALUES  ('000000225','asdf@gmail.com',NULL,5637146657),
                    ('000000225',NULL,'0612345678',5637176698)
        ) AS SQ1(PARTYID,MAIL,PHONE,RECID)
GROUP   BY SQ1.PARTYID;
```

Comment: Like I see that 2 mn ago?

Comment: Ok this indeed gets me the result I want, however now I selected only the PARTID 00000225, but in reality I have a table with half a million records. Is there a way to do this dynamically instead?

Comment: Sami's answer he has edited it as per your schema/original query, you just need to remove the where clause from it to return all the other party ids